# HTML/PHP Syntax to Move to Next Record Button

Tags: php, html

I am developing on an HTML page a "go to next record" button.

Well, it goes to the next record once and then stops. Nothing happens when clicking on the "Prior Issue" button after the initial click. Since I increment the issue number, the cursor should move to the next record. I am only working on the "Prior Issue" button currently.

HTML syntax:

```
<a href="index.php?content=main_window&id=1" title="Show More Recent Issue" >&#60; Next (Newer) Issue</a> &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp <a href="index.php?main_window&id=-1 title ="Show Older Issue" >Prior (Older)) Issue &#62;</a>
```

The variable "id" is past to:

```
// Get Cycle Direction "1" stands for newer issue, "0" No Direction set, "-1" stands for older issue
     if (!isset($_REQUEST['id']))
                {$cycle_direction=0;

            }  else  {

              $cycle_direction = trim($_REQUEST['id']);    
            }
```

---

Which then gets past to: (only working on the "case -1" at this time.

```
switch(trim($cycle_direction)) 
        {
            case -1:
               // display an older issue
                echo "Decrement<br>";
                $current_record_number=$current_record_number +1;
                echo $current_record_number;
                mysqli_data_seek($result, 0);       
                mysqli_data_seek($result, $current_record_number);
                $row=mysqli_fetch_row($result); 
                printf ("%s \n",$row[0]);   
                $issuenum=$row[0];                      
                break;
            case 0:
                // display current issue
                //echo "No Selection";
                break;
            case 1:
                // display newer issue 
                //echo "Increase";
                $issuenum=2165;
                break;
        }
```

Comment: well case 1 is hard coded to an issue number.  so um- what did you expect?

Comment: I hope you are saving $current_record_number in user's session or at least in cookies? If not, you will be surprised to realize PHP is stateless...

Comment: Unheiiig: Thanks for the response. I will have to examine it in greater detail. As you may have surmised, I an busy learning both HTML/CSS  and PHP.

Comment: Unheiiig: I should add that I do have a PHP array of issue numbers which provides the previous, current, and next issue numbers (primary key) for the query. So I thought I was beyond that issue. Maybe not. Clearly, I need to look at alternative approaches.

Comment: Dagon: The hard-coding was for testing purposes to verify that clicking on the pseudo "prior box" would work. Which it did.  I then added, for one case (case -1), the variable, which also worked; but only worked once. The issue is why the code only works once and not with each additional click.

Comment: In reflecting on the comments. Clicking on the pseudo next box works ONCE. That implies that the search of the PHP array and the subsequent MySQL query work. Since it does not work a second time, that means that I am somehow NOT changing the value of the PHP variable or that the HTML code is "disabled" for a second click.

Comment: You need to add the current issue record number to the `href`, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Beta" version now working. I stripped the code down to the very bare essentials and added many echo statements to observe how the program responded. The short answer, PHP does not have a memory between each web-page so the values of the variables are "lost".  While I was dimly aware of this, it did not become obvious for a while.

The solution was to develop a several *$_SESSION* variables to hold the array and to monitor the location of the cursor.

```
 <?php
 // Start the session
 session_start();
 include ("establish_array.php");
 ?>
```

The code below constitutes "*establish_array.php*" to establish the array in: "*$_SESSION['result']*".

```
<?php   
 require_once 'php_data/login_data.php';
 $conn = new mysqli($hn, $un, $pw, $db);
 if ($conn->connect_error) die($conn->connect_error.'   Sorry,   could       not   connect to the sfmags database server'); 
 $query = "Select IssueIDNUM FROM tblIssueList ORDER by IssueDate DESC,   IssueIDNUM ";
 $_SESSION['result'] =$conn->query($query);  
 if (!$_SESSION['result']) die($conn->error);
 $_SESSION['rowcount'] = mysqli_num_rows($_SESSION['result']);
 ?>
```

The code below is embedded in a case (switch) statement to move the magazine issue to the next older magazine when the pseudo "*next*" HTML key is pressed. The function "*return_row_number();*" returns the current row number, +1 is added to the row number and "*mysqli_data_seek*" is used to move to the next (older) record (issue).

```
            $issuenum = $_SESSION['issuenum']; 
            $_SESSION['cursor_location'] = return_row_number();
            echo "Cursor Location :" . $_SESSION['cursor_location'] . "<br>";
            $_SESSION['cursor_location'] = $_SESSION['cursor_location'] + 1;
                mysqli_data_seek($result, 0);   
                mysqli_data_seek($result,$_SESSION['cursor_location']);                 
                $row=mysqli_fetch_row($result); 
                $issuenum=$row[0];
                $_SESSION['issuenum'] = $issuenum; 
                echo "Issue Number: $issuenum <br>";
```

Thanks to: misunderstood, Unheiiig, and Alexander Ravikovich for providing useful advice and clues.

Answer (score 1):

Do it right way. All what you need is url with next/prev record's ids.

```
$current_id = isset($_GET['id']) ? intval($_GET['id']) : 0;

// in case you are using MySQL
$query = "SELECT 
    prev_id, next_id
FROM
    (SELECT 
        id AS prev_id
    FROM
        issues
    WHERE
        id < $current_id
    LIMIT 1) a,
    (SELECT 
        id AS next_id
    FROM
        issues
    WHERE
        id > $current_id
    LIMIT 1) b";

// fetch query data
$prev_id = ...
$next_id = ...

// SHOW CURRENT ISSUE

    echo '<a href="index.php?content=main_window&id='.$next_id.'" title="Show More Recent Issue" >&#60; Next (Newer) Issue</a> - <a href="index.php?main_window&id=$prev_id title ="Show Older Issue" >Prior (Older)) Issue &#62;</a>';
```

In case you get your data from any other db, the logic is the same. Just select previous and next ids, and provide urls using $prev_id and $next_id.

Another solution using MAX/MIN trick.

```
$query = "SELECT
        (SELECT MAX(id) FROM issues WHERE id < t.id) as prev_id,
        (SELECT MIN(id) FROM issues WHERE id > t.id) as next_id
FROM issues t WHERE t.id = $current_id";
```

Comment: If you look carefully, I don't talked about adding any fields to table. I just wrapped two queries by outer query. Such way you execute one query by PHP and get as result one row with two keys: $row['prev_id'] and $row['next_id']. MySQL sees it as one query with 2 sub-queries.

Comment: You posted two 2 queries - one select per query. I posted 1 query with 3 selects. Fields "prev_id, next_id" are just aliases. This is not correlated sub-queries. So, MySQL runs executes it very fast using indexes and other optimizations. Basically this means the query uses data that is directly available to MySQL and the query will run in constant time.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am just learning PHP and I am somewhat frustrated over the apparent inability to move the cursor through the array (recordset) as can be done with DAO.  Anyway, I do have an array that lists each issue's primary key in order where the rownumber for prior, current, and next issue are picked-up the $count variable ($count-1=next, $count=current, $count+1=prior). Since, what I have is not working, I do need to look at other approaches.

Answer (score -1):

### Update

This is what I got from your comment:

```
function return_row_number() {
 // Loop through the Array;  Get Row Number for the current issue global  $result,$issuenum, $rowcount; 
 $count =0; 
 mysqli_data_seek($result, 0); 
 while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { 
     ++$count; 
     if($issuenum == $row['IssueIDNUM']) { 
      return $count -1; break; 
     } 
   } 
 }
```

Now the mystery value is `$issuenum`.

And there is a terminology problem. This is not "Looping through an Array" it is querying the database and and looping through the query results.

This is a rather inefficient method of finding the next record.  But before correcting that, you need to explain where the value for `$issuenum` is coming from.

It would also help to know more about the  database table especially: 
How many issue records? 
What is the numbering scheme? 
How often does a new issue get added?

**end of update**

---

With this line of code you will always get a value of 1

`$current_record_number=$current_record_number +1;`

because `$current_record_number` = 0.

---

You should add the current issue to the `href` where xx=current record #.
I changed "id" to "cycle"
added `content=` to Next `href`.

```
<a href="index.php?content=main_window&cycle=1&rec=xx" 

title="Show More Recent Issue" >    &#60; Next (Newer) Issue</a>
&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp

<a href="index.php?content=main_window&cycle=-1&rec=xx

title ="Show Older Issue" >Prior (Older)) Issue &#62;</a>
```

Then add this to your PHP:

```
$current_record_number = intval($_GET['rec']);
```

And change:

```
$cycle_direction = trim($_REQUEST['id']);
```

To:

```
$cycle_direction= intval($_GET['cycle']);
```

---

Instead of `trim` and `isset` you should just  use `intval()`

```
$cycle_direction = intval($_REQUEST['id']);
```

Also instead of  `$current_record_number=$current_record_number +1;`

You could use: `$current_record_number += $cycle_direction`
and eliminate the switch.

---

Unconventional approach

Let's say issues have values from 1 to 10.

```
$next[-1] = array(0,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1);
$next[1] = array(0,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1);
$next[0] = array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10); 

$nextIssue = $next[intval($_REQUEST['id'])];
```

If issues are numbered 2001 to 2010

```
$nextIssue = 2000 + $next[intval($_REQUEST['id'])];
```

No matter how many issues you have there is no need to use a database.

Create the $next array as shown above, then save the array.

```
$fp = fopen('next.ser','w');
fwrite($fp,serialize($next));
fclose($fp);
```

When you need the $next array in an app use:

```
$next= unserialize(file_get_contents('next.ser'));
```

Comment: 1. In our days all the data stored in databases. 2. One query to db with indexes will take 0.00001 seconds even in 100k rows table. 3. After some time, ids becomes to be not consistent.

Comment: 4. He stores all data in database. 5. No need to rebuild something 6. No need to unnecessary hdd writings, serializing and so on.

Now, I want to see you using arrays for an exiting tables with 10k+ rows, every time that new record is added or deleted, read whole the tables id's, create 3 arrays, save it to hard disk and then every time you want use it, you need read it, unserialize it, find indexes... I'm sorry, but your solution is bad...

Comment: I'am already said all advantages that you get with just one simple SQL query. I don't want now get inside how db is using indexes and why this is faster of unserialize(file_get_contents()) when we talking about tables with 10k+ rows. Your solution has more code, more operations, uses more memory, bad for future customization and so on. Furthermore... you are using file for writing - now you need to care of new/delete operations for issues. What happens when 2 people are adding new issue to db, and your code attempts write data about new 2 issues the same time? Too many problems.

Comment: Yeah... and all this MySQL knows to do in 0.00001 seconds ;) And you get all advantages that I mentioned just with one row of code.

Comment: @AlexanderRavikovich please remove your comments.

Comment: The value of -1 is established by id=-1. The value of $current_record_number is established by cycling through the PHP array until the correct issue number (primary key) is located.

Comment: Thanks for taking a hard critical look at this. One issue, is posting too much stuff. but here goes.   Well the website protested my too long response.  <br/>  $current_record_number = return_row_number();

Comment: <?php

function return_row_number() 
 {  
  // Loop through the Array; Get Row Number for the current issue
  global $result,$issuenum, $rowcount;
  $count =0;
  mysqli_data_seek($result, 0);
  while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
     {
        ++$count;
        if($issuenum == $row['IssueIDNUM'])
        {
     return $count -1;
     break;      
        }
         } 
 } 
?>